# What is the workflow for Stripe's Custom Payment?

Tags: javascript, django, stripe-payments, python-stripe-api

I am currently developing a payment module for my django application and I am seeking assistance. Presently, my application uses [Checkout Stripe](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout) for payment processing, but I find it limiting because it doesn't allow me to fully customize the checkout page according to my preferences. Additionally, I would like to keep the users on my website during the payment process.

While exploring Stripe's documentation, I came across the "[Custom Payment Flow](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/quickstart?lang=python)" feature, which seems to be what I need. My desired flow is as follows: when a user clicks on the "Buy product" button, they should be redirected to a checkout page that I have customized using HTML. This checkout page will include product details, a form to collect personal information, and the Stripe payment form below.

I understand that when the page loads, I need to update a variable called items using jQuery or JavaScript to populate it with the specific item or items the user intends to purchase.

```
// The items the customer wants to buy
const items = [{ id: "xl-tshirt" }];
```

However, I am unsure about how to handle the personal information that I will collect from the user.

Could someone please provide guidance on how to proceed with this integration?

Comment: what do you want to do with the personal information from the customer and what specifically are you unsure about handling?

Answer (score 0):

> I understand that when the page loads, I need to update a variable called items using jQuery or JavaScript to populate it with the specific item or items the user intends to purchase.

The reason for this `items` dict is to avoid sending the payment amount as a numerical value. Doing so is dangerous, since you don't want your customers to manipulate the amount you're going to charge them.

As for the information to collect from the customer:
If you're following the [official Stripe documentation](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment?platform=web&ui=elements), you're implementing a `payment` element, which includes all required fields for each payment method (with some nuances - technically the country field is not required with the `card` element, however the `payment` element requires it regardless).

Some fields might be missing for your own processes - the fields of a `payment` element don't include the email field for instance.
If you want to add those fields, you can do so yourself, or use Stripe's `address` [element](https://stripe.com/docs/elements/address-element).

Ultimately, the answer to your question about customer information largely depends of what information is necessary for your processes.